# Python pandas spot the time difference in a dataframe efficiently for consecutive rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
   payeeId     amount       createdAt                          TrxnID
    1001        2.30      2021-04-24 01:40:11.156000+00:00     100AA
    1001        35        2021-04-24 02:10:11.146000+00:00     100AB
    1001        600       2021-04-24 02:12:14.309000+00:00     100AC
    1002        100       2021-04-24 02:59:51.127000+00:00     110BD
    1003        1900      2021-04-24 04:09:15.113000+00:00     120AC
    1003        10        2021-04-24 04:19:40.132000+00:00     120AM
```

I want to add a flag with the below logic:

```
  If for a given 'PayeeId', the difference between two consecutive 'createdAt' is less than 300 seconds, then the flag will be set to 'No Settlement', else 'Approved'
```

So the resultant Dataframe would look like

```
     payeeId    amount       createdAt                          TrxnID    Flag
      1001       2.30      2021-04-24 01:40:11.156000+00:00     100AA    Approved
      1001       35        2021-04-24 02:10:11.146000+00:00     100AB    Approved
      1001       600       2021-04-24 02:12:14.309000+00:00     100AC    Not Approved
      1002       100       2021-04-24 02:59:51.127000+00:00     110BD    Approved
      1003       1900      2021-04-24 04:09:15.113000+00:00     120AC    Approved
      1003       10        2021-04-24 04:19:40.132000+00:00     120AM    Approved
```

So I am trying with following code snippets:

```
gs = df.groupby(['payeeId'])['createdAt']
df['Time_Diff'] = gs.diff().fillna(pd.Timedelta(seconds=0))/pd.Timedelta(seconds=300)
df['Flag'] = np.where(df_sub_count['Time_Diff']>0,'Approved','No Settlement')
```

But the above one is not generating the desired result. I see 'No Settlement' for `payeeID` 1002. Which is not desirable.

What am I missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['createdAt'] = pd.to_datetime(df.createdAt)

diff_sec=300.
mask= df.groupby('payeeId').createdAt.diff().astype('timedelta64[s]').fillna(diff_sec)
df['Flag'] = np.where(mask >= diff_sec, 'Approved', 'Not Approved') # plz replace 'Not Approved' with 'No Settlement' based on requirement.
```

**Output**

```
    payeeId amount  createdAt                     TrxnID    Flag
0   1001    2.3 2021-04-24 01:40:11.156000+00:00    100AA   Approved
1   1001    35.0    2021-04-24 02:10:11.146000+00:00    100AB   Approved
2   1001    600.0   2021-04-24 02:12:14.309000+00:00    100AC   Not Approved
3   1002    100.0   2021-04-24 02:59:51.127000+00:00    110BD   Approved
4   1003    1900.0  2021-04-24 04:09:15.113000+00:00    120AC   Approved
5   1003    10.0    2021-04-24 04:19:40.132000+00:00    120AM   Approved
```

**Explanation**.

We are grouping the df by `payeeId` and fetching the diff between `createdAt` in seconds.
Since we want the first occurrence of each `payeeId` to be approve hence filling na with 300.
Then we are using `np.where` to create `Flag` column based on condition.